# What does the 'static lifetime mean in a trait bound in a Rust future?

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-tokio

I thought that I've got what the `'static` lifetime is, but now I'm not sure.

I'm trying to understand how to work with Tokio and Futures. My app is working, but the structure is awful, so I need to decompose it. Here comes `'static` requirement for my closures, that I don't know how to resolve.

For example, in a `main` function I have a handle and able to `spawn` a future to its loop:

```
let mut core = tokio_core::reactor::Core::new().unwrap();
let handle = core.handle();
let future = {
    ok(())
};
```

It compiles; now I want to move some logic out:

```
struct Test;
impl Test {
    fn test(&self, handle: tokio_core::reactor::Handle) {
        let future = {
            ok(())
        };
        handle.spawn(future);
    }
}
```

It compiles too. When my struct gets more complicated:

```
struct Test<'a> {
    api: &'a Arc<Api>,
}

impl<'a> Test<'a> {
    fn new(api: &'a Arc<Api>) -> Self {
        Test {
            api: api,
        }
    }

    fn test(&self, msg: &telegram_bot::types::Message, handle: tokio_core::reactor::Handle) {
        let api = self.api.clone();
        let future = ok(10);
        let future2 = move |x| {
            api.send(msg.text_reply(format!("reply: {}", x))) // returns Future
        }.map(|_| ()).map_err(|_| ()); // let's ignore the results for now
        handle.spawn(future.and_then(future2));
    }
}
```

... I run into

```
error[E0477]: the type `futures::AndThen<futures::FutureResult<i32, ()>, futures::FutureResult<(), ()>, [closure@src/main.rs:63:23: 66:10 api:std::sync::Arc<telegram_bot::Api>, msg:&telegram_bot::Message]>` does not fulfill the required lifetime
handle.spawn(future.and_then(future2));
       ^^^^^
note: type must satisfy the static lifetime
```

I think it yells about my closure. The same future works if I have it in the `main` function with my `Arc`'ed `Api`.

Moving this to a struct with references like a separate "processor" break it with `'static` errors.

Comment: *I thought that I've got what the 'static lifetime is* — what did you think it was? Why do you think that `api` has the `'static` lifetime?

Comment: @Shepmaster, I thought that `'static` lifetime is used to indicate data which is placed in `.bss` sector, like string literals known in compile time. I'm not sure that `api` has the `'static` lifetime, but I see in docs that `spawn` method needs this lifetime for it's argument. I don't know why it is `'static` in `main` function, where there are no errors.

Comment: `fn spawn<F>(&self, f: F) where F: Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + 'static ` I mean

Comment: TL;DR the duplicates: the `'static` *bound* on a generic type requires that any references inside the type must live as least as long as `'static`. If your type has no references, it meets the bounds. If it has references, they must be `'static`.

Comment: @Shepmaster, oh, I got it, thank you. If I set the reference to `msg` to `'static` it compiles, but it won't clean old messages, right?

Comment: Do you mean `fn test(&self, msg: &'static Message, handle: Handle)`? If so, then you will only be able to pass in `Message`s that live for the entire life of the program (which is probably not what you want). Instead, you should probably just take in a `Message` by value and move it into the closure / future. In that case, you will have no lifetimes, thus you will meet the `'static` bounds. I'd also recommend storing just an `Arc<Api>` in your `Test`, not a `&'a Arc<Api>`.

Comment: Suddenly it became totally clear for me. Thank you very much, @Shepmaster, for your work for the community.

Comment: You are very welcome! I hope you enjoy working with Rust as much as we do!