# Do non-reference types always satisfy a lifetime of 'static?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to understand why the code below compiles. I wasn't expecting to be able to construct `Wrapper<String>` since `T: 'static` and runtime-allocated strings don't live for the entire lifetime of the program.

I think the reason this is allowed is because I'm setting `T` to a non-reference type (`String`). When I use a `&str`, or a struct containing a reference, the compiler issues the error I'd expect.

However, I haven't been able to find anything in the Rust docs that confirms my hypothesis, so maybe I don't fully understand the rules. Will all non-reference types satisfy the `'static` lifetime bound on `Wrapper<T>`, or are there some that will fail?

```rust
use rand::Rng;

struct Wrapper<T>
where
    T: 'static,
{
    value: T,
}

fn wrap_string() -> Wrapper<String> {
    // Use rng to avoid construcing string at compile time
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let n: u8 = rng.gen();
    let text = format!("The number is {}", n);
    Wrapper { value: text }
}

fn main() {
    let wrapped = wrap_string();
    std::mem::drop(wrapped);
}
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the (duplicate) answers of [What does the 'static lifetime mean in a trait bound in a Rust future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48504103/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I think this question is more specifically asking why a type which doesn't have a static lifetime would still satisfy the bound `T: 'static`. That seems different to the more general questions asked in the linked question and the ones it's marked as a duplicate of. (FWIW, I couldn't work out the answer to this question just by reading those answers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Background section of RFC 2093](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2093-infer-outlives.md#background-outlives-requirements-today):

> [...] in order for a reference type &'a T to be "well formed" (valid),
>   the compiler must know that the type T "outlives" the lifetime 'a --
>   meaning that all references contained in the type T must be valid for
>   the lifetime 'a. So, for example, the type i32 outlives any lifetime,
>   including 'static, since it has no references at all.

So I'd say the answer to your question is: yes, any type which has no references (or which only contains static references) satisfies the `'static` bound.

Side note: according to that RFC, bounds like `T: 'static` and `T: 'a` are known as `outlives requirements`.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of a type bound `T: 'x` as "Instances of `T` cannot suddenly become invalid because something that lives shorter than `'x` was dropped.". However, this does not affect how long the instance of `T` itself lives.

So, a reference becomes invalid if the referenced thing is dropped. Which means that the referenced thing must live at least as long as `'x` - for the entire run of the program in the case of `'static`.

But something that own all its data - an `i32` or a `String` for example - never becomes invalid because something else is dropped. An integer is good until it is dropped itself. So it satisfies the `'static` bound.