# Is my understanding of static trait bounds correct?

Tags: rust, traits

I am using the specs ECS library and I have the following type

```
trait TradeableResource{}

#[derive(Component)]
struct MarketMaker<T: TradeableResource + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync + 'static>{
    lot_size:T
}
```

This does not compile without the `'static` constraint. I was initially concerned that this would mean that all values of this struct will have to live for the entire life of the program, [but](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html#trait-bound) [looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504103/what-does-the-static-lifetime-mean-in-a-trait-bound-in-a-rust-future) [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053550/the-compiler-suggests-i-add-a-static-lifetime-because-the-parameter-type-may-no), it seems the concern is invalid. Those links clearly deal with the topic but I feel they don't use language that results in a clear mental model for me. So I'd like to make my own statement about the topic, and you tell me if I am correct.

**My statement**

By using the `'static` constraint, any type that fills the place of `T` must *either*

1. Consist entirely of owned values, or
2. If it contains referenced values, those must live as long as the lifetime of the program.

So the following specific case would not require anything to live the entire life of the program

```
#[derive(Component)]
struct Food(f64);
impl TradeableResource for Food{}

fn main() {
    let mut world = World::new();
    world.register::<MarketMaker<Food>>();

    world.create_entity().with(MarketMaker { lot_size: Food(4.0)}).build();
}
```

Because the type `Food` contains only owned values, no references.

Have I got that right?

Comment: Put differently, the `'static` constraint means all references in the type live for the static lifetime. If there are no references, this statement is trivially true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: yes, you got it correctly.

Indeed `'static` term is a lit bit overloaded. It can be used as a lifetime specifier, e.g:

```rust
const T: &'static str = "static string here";

fn handle_static<T>(t: &'static T) { .. }
```

and as the type bound:

```rust
trait T: 'static { .. }

fn handle_owned<T>(t: T)
where T: 'static { .. }
```

These are fairly different cases and yours example is similar to the second one. Your statements are correct and the following example illustrates it ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b3e7431a2b60340596b1e526f31418e6)):

```rust
struct X<'a> {
    borrowed_str: &'a str,
}

let base_str = "".to_string();
// X'es lifetime bounded by base_str
let borrows = X {
    borrowed_str: base_str.as_str(),
};
let borrows_static = X { borrowed_str: "" };

fn f<T>(t: T) where T: 'static {}

// the following line fails to compile
// f(borrowed);

f(borrows_static); // though, with 'static lifetime works
f(base_str); // owned, also works fine
```

I also suggest you to look at amazing [Common Rust Lifetime Misconceptions](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md) post if you want a structured guide to that or similar misconceptions.

Comment: I think you mean my example is similar to the second one, right?

Comment: Oops, pasted examples in the wrong order, the second one indeed. Fixed it, thanks

Comment: It's not really `'static` that's overloaded, since you can apply `T: 'a` bounds with any lifetime with the same meaning.