# How do I obtain a trait object from a wrapper trait object with an associated type?

Tags: rust, associated-types

I have two traits `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
trait Bar {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str;
}

trait Foo {
    type B: Bar + ?Sized;

    fn get_bar(&self) -> &Self::B;
}
```

In reality, I'll have many different types of `Foo`s and `Bar`s but each `Foo` has the associated trait for a type of `Bar`. Keeping it simple for now, the `SimpleFoo` is associated with the `SimpleBar`:

```
struct SimpleBar {
    name: String,
}

impl Bar for SimpleBar {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &str {
        &self.name
    }
}

struct SimpleFoo {
    bar: Rc<SimpleBar>,
}

impl Foo for SimpleFoo {
    type B = SimpleBar;

    fn get_bar(&self) -> &SimpleBar {
        &self.bar
    }
}
```

In some places I can use generics and monomorphism, but I need dynamic dispatch in some locations, like this function than needs a `dyn Foo` whose `Bar` is a `dyn Bar`:

```
fn some_func_that_needs_dyn_foo_returning_a_dyn_bar(foo: &dyn Foo<B = dyn Bar>) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Since `SimpleFoo` implements `Foo<B = SimpleBar>` not `Foo<B = dyn Bar>` I can't directly pass it (I wish the compiler or a derive or something could do magic here and make this possible), so I have a wrapper class which holds a reference to some specific `Foo` and can get its specific `Bar` and make it into a `dyn Bar`:

```
struct DynamicFooWrapper<'a, F: Foo> {
    foo: &'a F,
}

impl<'a, F> Foo for DynamicFooWrapper<'a, F>
where
    F: Foo,
    <F as Foo>::B: Sized,
{
    type B = dyn Bar;

    fn get_bar(&self) -> &'a Self::B {
        self.foo.get_bar()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b = Rc::new(SimpleBar {
        name: "Bar101".to_owned(),
    });
    let f = SimpleFoo { bar: b.clone() };
    some_func_that_needs_dyn_foo_returning_a_dyn_bar(&DynamicFooWrapper { foo: &f })
}
```

It's unhappy about the return lifetimes is in the implementation of the wrapper:

```
error[E0310]: the associated type `<F as Foo>::B` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:45:9
   |
45 |         self.foo.get_bar()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `<F as Foo>::B: 'static`...
   = note: ...so that the type `<F as Foo>::B` will meet its required lifetime bounds

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0310`.
```

I don't want to have any static data here. I'd like to tie the lifetime of the `&dyn Bar` returned here to the lifetime of the `foo` which the `DynamicFooWrapper` wraps because that `&dyn Bar` will live at least as long as the wrapped `Foo`. For instance, after calling `get_bar()` on the `Foo` wrapper, I'd even like to destroy the `Foo` wrapper and as long as the original `Foo` item is alive. It should be possible since that guarantees the lifetime of `Bar` - I'm just not sure how to express this all.

Comment: Could you send some playground code to work with?

Comment: Would [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4874b0f619e3ad39003c7cbcdced5cd9) solve your problem?

Comment: *I don't want to have any static data here* — Read the dupes linked off [What does the 'static lifetime mean in a trait bound in a Rust future?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48504103/155423) and [this TL;DR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504103/what-does-the-static-lifetime-mean-in-a-trait-bound-in-a-rust-future#comment84004134_48504103). Are you sure you understand it the right way?

Comment: Re: I wish the compiler or a derive or something could do magic here and make this possible, this might become possible with the work done for async fn in traits. See the series "Dyn async traits" from Niko (the last one is [here](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps//blog/2022/01/07/dyn-async-traits-part-7/)).

Comment: Thanks @Jmb , that works! But what does it mean do have the lifetime here:
`fn some_func_that_needs_dyn_foo_returning_a_dyn_bar<'a>(_foo: &dyn Foo<B=dyn Bar + 'a>)`, the `dyn Bar +'a`. I know it won't won't matter compile-wise since all the lifetimes are erased but what does it "prove" to rustc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL/DR:** You need to use `dyn Bar + 'a` instead of plain `dyn Bar`:

```
fn some_func_that_needs_dyn_foo_returning_a_dyn_bar<'a>(_foo: &dyn Foo<B=dyn Bar + 'a>) {
    // do stuff
}

struct DynamicFooWrapper<'a, F: Foo> {
    foo: &'a F,
}

impl<'a, F> Foo for DynamicFooWrapper<'a, F>
where
    F: Foo,
    <F as Foo>::B: Sized,
{
    type B = dyn Bar + 'a;

    fn get_bar(&self) -> &'a Self::B {
        self.foo.get_bar()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b = Rc::new(SimpleBar {name: "Bar101".to_owned()});
    let f = SimpleFoo { bar: b.clone() };
    some_func_that_needs_dyn_foo_returning_a_dyn_bar(&DynamicFooWrapper{foo: &f})
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4874b0f619e3ad39003c7cbcdced5cd9)

At some point the `dyn Bar + 'a` will be matched with some concrete type `T`. The `+ 'a` constraint tells the compiler that if `T` contains references, then these references live at least as long as `'a`. This is required if you want to take a reference to `T` with lifetime `'a` as in `&'a Self::B`.